# How can I prevent a Leaflet popup from redirecting to other page or change the href

Tags: javascript, vue.js, popup, vue2leaflet

I am working on a vue2leaflet map (https://vue2leaflet.netlify.app/components/LPopup.html#demo ), the vue2leaflet map has a default href="close", so when clicked on the (X) it redirect me to this `#close.`
Is there a way in vue2leaflet map to modify this ref or disable the href redirection ?
and also how can I access this selector `'.leaflet-pane.leaflet-popup-pane'`  via ref in vue.

my code :
in template

```
 <l-popup ref="closep">
   <slot name="popup" v-bind="{ location }" />
 </l-popup>
```

```
in <script>
--------------------
 mounted() {
    this.$refs.closep
    console.log("popup close.... , this.$refs.closep); // gives me undefined
  },
```